# XSLT missing elements not all been added

Tags: xml, xslt

My XSLT is not adding all the missing elements. 
I need to put in the fields  and

Here is the XML I'm using.

```
<Report>
   <Table>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <Name>R2D2</Name>
   </Table>
   <Table>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Name>T1000</Name>
   </Table>
</Report>
```

Here is the XSLT. (I would like to use either XSLT 2 or 3 if possible)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Table[not(Address)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <Address/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Table[not(City)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <City/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting this result where for some reason Address is missing!

```
<Report>
   <Table>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <Name>RD2</Name>
      <City/>
   </Table>
   <Table>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Name>ZZZZ</Name>
      <City/>
   </Table>
</Report>
```

I'm expecting to get this kind of result. here if Address and City are missing, they are included.

```
<Report>
   <Table>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <Name>RD2</Name>
      <Address/>
      <City/>
   </Table>
   <Table>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Name>ZZZZ</Name>
      <Address/>
      <City/>
   </Table>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for some reason Address is missing!

Address is missing because a Table without Address and without City is matched by all three of your templates, two of them with the same priority - and only the last one of these is applied - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict

Here's one way you could solve this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Table[not(Address and City)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="not(Address)">
            <Address/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(City)">
            <City/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you michael.hor257k. Solved my issue, but also pointed to me to the conflict I wasn't aware was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Table[not(City) and not(Address)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <Address/>
        <City/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This will not add City if only City is missing. Or Address if only Address is missing.